# Padding around <a> tags not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I can't get IE padding around my <a> tags to work correctly. This only works in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, but not IE - please help!

My simplified HTML code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <div id="mydiv">
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
         <a style="padding: 20px; background: red;" href="#">Some link</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

Firefox Result (which is what I want):

[image]

Internet Explorer (7) Result (incorrect padding):

[(broken image)](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8555/linkissueie.jpg)

How can I fix this to work in IE? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For elements which are naturally inline, IE requires that the element have the `display: inline-block;` css property before it will apply properties like `padding`.  So just add `display: inline-block` to your anchor element.

```
<a style="display: inline-block; padding: 20px; background: red;" href="#">Some link</a>
```

Comment: Wow. I'm not a Microsoft hater but this was a tough nut damn IE! Thank you!