# CSS <div> not scaling well between IE and Firefox

Tags: css

I'm having trouble resizing my template to look the same as IE.
I'm trying to make the div called face 3 and face4 scale on both IE and firefox but I just can't . If an div fit perfectly well on Firefox . then it would go over on IE . Can someone please help me .
[image]

#### CSS

```
.face1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #AAAAAA; 
    height: 450px;
    width: 390px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 520px;top:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#1BE968;
    border-width:35px;
}
.face3 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #DDDDDD; 
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;top:0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 33px;
}
.face4 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;  
    width: 50px;height:30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 290px;top:200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 33px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="face1">
    <div class="face3">24 x 7 customer web supprt</div>
    <div class="face4">supprt</div>
</div>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Yg3yq/

Comment: Well, thank you for posting a question including images! Makes it easy to understand what you mean :)

Comment: @xec can I also ask , do you know padding? everytime I use on firefox , it works but on IE it doesn't how come?

Comment: Without a specific use case, it's hard to tell. You could try to search through SO earlier questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463267 might be relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening http://jsfiddle.net/Yg3yq/show/ in IE8 (and IE9) renders the same as Firefox, which leads me to believe your document might be rendered in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

To remedy this, make this the first line of your HTML file (no whitespace or characters before it!)

```
<!document html>
```